# Git: How to find uncommitted changes so far?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Here is the situation I ran into:

When I tried to `git pull`, I found my collaborator had committed some changes, hence got the following error message.

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    template.tex
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

So I want to know **what changes I have made so far since my last commit**, so that I can decide to commit them or stash them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you haven't added any new files, you can just simply run `git diff` on a terminal for the specific changes. Running `git status` would show the file changes to be committed for the next commit.